# how to get the next or previous to active cell with avoiding invisible rows

Tags: excel, vba

I want to get the next or previous to active cell based on list of visible rows.

and I tested tow approach to do that

first approach :
get range of visible rows like this.

```
Public rng_arr As Range

Public Sub UserForm_Activate()
Set rng_arr = Range(ActiveCell, Cells(ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Row, 1)).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
End Sub
```

but I don't know how to correspond the selected cell with its opposites in my range rng_arr to get the next or previous cell.

---

second approach :
get the next of active cell but can't get the previous.

```
Public Function NextVisibleCell(Range As Range) As Range
Application.Volatile
Dim i As Long
Set Range = Range.Cells(Range.Rows.Count, Range.Columns.Count)
 For i = 1 To Rows.Count - Range.Row
  If Not Range.Offset(i).EntireRow.Hidden Then
    Set NextVisibleCell = Range.Offset(i)
    Exit Function
  End If
 Next i
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

finally I found a good solution using second approach and its working will.
there is my code.

```
Public Function NextVisibleCell(Range As Range) As Range

Dim i As Long
Set Range = Range.Cells(Range.Rows.Count, Range.Columns.Count)
For i = 1 To Rows.Count - Range.Row
If Not Range.Offset(i).EntireRow.Hidden Then
    Set NextVisibleCell = Range.Offset(i)
    Exit Function
End If
Next i
End Function
```

---

```
Public Function PrevVisibleCell(Range As Range) As Range
Dim isvisble As Boolean
isvisble = False
Dim i As Long
i = 1
Do Until isvisble = True
If Not Range.Offset(-i, 0).EntireRow.Hidden Then
isvisble = True
Set PrevVisibleCell = Range.Offset(-i, 0)
End If
i = i + 1
Loop
End Function
```

and i can call any one of them like the following

```
NextVisibleCell(ActiveCell).Select

PrevVisibleCell(ActiveCell).Select
```

Comment: why the `Application.Volatile` if not used as UDF?

Comment: honestly the first one are quoted by only the second one is my thought

Answer (score 0):

As a different solution which can do a bit more, try this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function nVC(rng As Range, goDir As XlDirection) As Range
  Set rng = rng.Resize(1, 1)

  If (goDir = xlDown Or goDir = xlUp) Then
    If rng.Width = 0 Then Exit Function
    If goDir = xlDown Then Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0) Else Set rng = rng.Offset(-1, 0)

    While rng.Row > 1 And rng.Row < Rows.Count And rng.Height = 0
      If goDir = xlDown Then Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0) Else Set rng = rng.Offset(-1, 0)
    Wend

    If rng.Height > 0 Then Set nVC = rng

  ElseIf (goDir = xlToRight Or goDir = xlToLeft) Then

    If rng.Height = 0 Then Exit Function
    If goDir = xlToRight Then Set rng = rng.Offset(0, 1) Else Set rng = rng.Offset(0, -1)

    While rng.Column > 1 And rng.Column < Rows.Count And rng.Width = 0
      If goDir = xlToRight Then Set rng = rng.Offset(0, 1) Else Set rng = rng.Offset(0, -1)
    Wend

    If rng.Width > 0 Then Set nVC = rng

  End If
End Function
```